# How to join these tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
users
-----------------------------------
id | firstname | lastname | username
-----------------------------------
1  | John     | Doe      | jdoe
-----------------------------------
2  | Maria    | T.       | marty
-----------------------------------
3  | Alex     | White    | alexw
-----------------------------------

questions
--------------------------------------------
id | user_id | title
--------------------------------------------
1  | 2       | My first question?
--------------------------------------------
2  | 3       | One more question?
--------------------------------------------
3  | 3       | The third question?
--------------------------------------------

answers
----------------------------------------------
id | question_id | description
----------------------------------------------
1  | 2           | Answers to the 2nd question
----------------------------------------------
2  | 1           | Answer for 1st question
----------------------------------------------
3  | 1           | Another answer for 1st
----------------------------------------------
```

Now,I want to retrieve all question with user's(asker's) firstname, lastname, username and count of total answers given for a question.

Please help writing it. Since I have messed my query, not posted here.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you use a id for users when you can have the username as Primary Key?

Comment: Don't you mean count of total answers given for *a question*?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: just because there's a record `id` field, it doesn't make it the primary key, however it's usually always good to have this.  Imagine if you structure your table to have active dates, you could have the same `username` (primary key could be *username* + *date field*), but the record `id` will still be unique.

Comment: 'fistname' should of course be 'firstname', in the first table. The edit feature won't permit less than six trivial corrections, so perhaps the OP or a moderator can make the correction?

Comment: +1 for having a separate primary key. @AurelioDeRosa, the OP could add a unique constraint on 'username' in this case, but having a separate integer PK is fine.

Comment: Yes! I want to count answers given for a question.

Comment: @vol7ron You're right but this is not the case. In a table named USERS there's the primary key should be username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT q.*, u.*, COUNT(a.id) as answer_count
FROM questions q 
LEFT JOIN users u ON q.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.id
GROUP BY q.id
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need a group by in there

Comment: if you have `q.*,u.*` you're going to need to group by more than just `q.id`.  you'll have to join by `u.id, firstname, lastname, username, q.id, user_id, title`

Comment: @vol7ron q.id is the primary key, why it is not enough for group by?

Comment: @vol7ron: Not in MySQL. This is a 100% valid (MySQL) query that returns what is being asked.

Comment: (although I'd have used: `users LEFT JOIN questions LEFT JOIN answers` to also show users that have not asked any questions.)

Comment: @xdazz has given the answer I wanted. His query is 100% right.

Comment: @xdazz: it may be in mysql, but I think if you wanted to have cross-database SQL, you would specify all non-aggregate fields in the `group by` clause

Answer (score -1):

```
select users.fistname,users.lastname,users.username 
from users, questions, answers
where users.id = questions.user_id and questions.id = answers.question_id
```

Comment: The requirement is perhaps not 100% clear, but I am guessing that all questions must be listed, even if no users have answered them. On that basis I reckon you need some left joins in there, as per @xdazz.

Comment: All questions must be listed, but your query give redundant questions.

Yes, even no user has answered it.